# Access names of fields in struct Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to 'lift' the fields of a struct to the top level in a dataframe, as illustrated by this example:

```
case class A(a1: String, a2: String)
case class B(b1: String, b2: A)

val df = Seq(B("X",A("Y","Z"))).toDF

df.show    
+---+-----+
| b1|   b2|
+---+-----+
|  X|[Y,Z]|
+---+-----+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- b1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a2: string (nullable = true)

val lifted = df.withColumn("a1", $"b2.a1").withColumn("a2", $"b2.a2").drop("b2")

lifted.show
+---+---+---+
| b1| a1| a2|
+---+---+---+
|  X|  Y|  Z|
+---+---+---+

lifted.printSchema
 root
 |-- b1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a2: string (nullable = true)
```

This works. I would like to create a little utility method which does this for me, probably through pimping DataFrame to enable something like df.lift("b2").

To do this, I think I want a way of obtaining a list of all fields within a Struct. E.g. given "b2" as input, return ["a1","a2"]. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to list the nested fields of column b2.

So you would need to filter on `b2`, access the `StructType` of `b2` and then map the names of the columns from within the fields (`StructField`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

val nested_fields = df.schema
                   .filter(c => c.name == "b2")
                   .flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields)
                   .map(_.name)

// nested_fields: Seq[String] = List(a1, a2)
```

Comment: You can skip the `filter` by using `df.schema("b2")`.

Comment: pyspark version if anyone needs it: `next(col for col in df.schema if col.name==colName).dataType.fieldNames()`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use ".fieldNames.toList".

```
val nested_fields = df.schema("b2").fieldNames.toList
```

It returns a list of String. If you want a list of columns make a map.

I hope it helps.